# Export Variable from watch in Visual Studio as Json to Compare it

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

Is there a way to export a variable from the visual studio watch window as json? I have a very large object that I am loading via two different formats of configuration file and I want to see if both are loading the same values and if not what the differences are using something like tortoise diff. This is visual studio 2010.

I don't think it matters but it is a c# project